# Unity | basic pathfinding on a sphere

Tags: unity

I have 2 characters on a sphere. I would like one would move toward the other along the shortest way. How would I go about that?

Comment: Are there any obstacles on your sphere, or can they dead reckon toward each other along a geodesic arc (a great circle)?

Comment: Nope, no obstacles for now. I know this might be very easy with my current requirements, but I have some weird rotations from time to time. Basically I use Sebastien's script (https://github.com/SebLague/Spherical-Gravity) for faux planet gravity. The script always correctly rotates the body to stay on the planet. To move NPCs toward the player I use LookAt(player) and then rigidbody.MovePosition. This works fine most of time, until NPCs get closer and the player starts jumping. I guess my LookAt here is what causes this...

Comment: @DMGregory, any help on this basic setup? Just moving one object towards another along the shortest arc (no obstacles) making sure its bottom is always touches the surface?